# MongoError: cursor killed or timed out

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to process data in my MongoDB database by streaming it, pause, process, and resume. The processing can take up to 2-3 minutes for each document, each being done by a worker in a cluster. I stream the document in the `master` then send the document to the `workers` to be process. The problem is I am getting the error `MongoError: cursor killed or timed out` 20-30 minutes into the stream ( or about 10+ documents). I have successfully use this method before when the processing time is lower than this.

Configuration:
`node-mongodb-native@1.4.40`,`mongodb version 3.0.5`,`node 0.10`

```
MongoClient.connect(config.mongodb, function(err, db) {
  if (err) helper.logError(err)
  var collection = db.collection('collectionName');
  stream = collection.find(condition).stream();
  stream.on("data", function(doc) {
    stream.pause();
    doSomeProcessing().then(function(){
      stream.resume()
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Nope, I redesign how I query it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the cursor timeout by adding the `'noCursorTimeout'` flag to the cursor returned by `find()` by calling [`addCursorFlag`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag):

```js
stream = collection.find(condition).addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true).stream();
```

Comment: the driver version 1.4 doesn't have that flag, it has a timeout option, but that doesn't work.